# How to write pairwiseAlignment in R in Fasta Format with Headers?

Tags: r

I try to write an R-script with which I can align a bench of sequences in one file with a single sequence in another file.

So far, I'm really happy with the results, but I have one big problem. How to write the pairwiseAlignment output in fasta format WITH header names?

I did this (among others):

```
seq1 <- readDNAStringSet("file1.fasta", use.names=T)
seq2 <- readDNAStringSet("file2.fasta", use.names=T)

mat <- nucleotideSubstitutionMatrix(match = 1, mismatch = -3, baseOnly= F)

# here I will introduce a loop with sapply() to align every sequence against 
# the sequence in file2

globalAlign <- pairwiseAlignment(seq1[1], seq2[1], type='global-local',   
substitutionMatrix=mat, gapOpening=10, gapExtension=-5)

r = BStringSet( c(toString(subject(globalAlign)), toString(pattern(globalAlign))) )
writeXStringSet(r,"out1.txt")
```

But my "out1.txt"-outfile looks like this:

```
>
ATGCGATGCTAGCTGCATAGCTCGATCG

>
ATGCGAT---AGCTGCATAGCT---TCG
```

Has anyone of you an idea how to include the sequence names so that it will look like this:

```
>seq_name_1

ATGCGATGCTAGCTGCATAGCTCGATCG

>seq_name_2

ATGCGAT---AGCTGCATAGCT---TCG
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add names to the DNAStringSet

```
r = c(as(subject(globalAlign), "DNAStringSet"), 
      as(pattern(globalAlign), "DNAStringSet"))
names(r) = c("subject", "pattern")
writeXStringSet(r, "out.fasta")
```

leading to

```
>subject
GTTTCACTACTTCCTTTCGGGTAAGTAAATATATAAATATATAAAAATATAATTTTCATC
>pattern
ACTTCACCAGCTCCCTGGCGGTAAGTTGATC---AAAGG---AAACGCAAAGTTTTCAAG
```

The Bioconductor [support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org) is a more appropriate place for questions about Bioconductor packages.

Comment: So, to tag the sequences with their original unaligned names: names(r) <- c(names(unaligned(subject(globalAlign))),
              names(unaligned(pattern(globalAlign))))